# Simple Example of AdwViewSwitcher from libadwaita

Tags: c, gnome, gobject, gtk4

I can't get `AdwViewSwitcher` to show anything. I don't get any sort of errors, but nothing shows. This is my code:

```
PRIVATE GtkWidget *window = NULL;
PRIVATE GtkWidget *pref   = NULL;

PRIVATE GtkWidget *theme = NULL;

PRIVATE GtkFontDialog *font_dialog = NULL;
PRIVATE GtkWidget     *font        = NULL;

PRIVATE GtkWidget *about = NULL;

PRIVATE GtkWidget *view   = NULL;
PRIVATE GtkWidget *stack1 = NULL;
PRIVATE GtkWidget *stack2 = NULL;
PRIVATE GtkWidget *button = NULL;

PRIVATE
void theme_ev(GtkWidget *widget, GParamSpec *param_spec, gpointer user_data) {
        SDL_Log("Theme");
}

PRIVATE
void font_ev(GtkWidget *widget, GParamSpec *param_spec, gpointer user_data) {
        SDL_Log("Font");
}

PRIVATE
void about_ev(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data) {
        adw_show_about_window(GTK_WINDOW(window), 
                              "application-name", "Editor Example",
                              NULL);
}

API
SDL_bool SetupEditor(GtkApplication *app, gpointer *unused) {
        SDL_DisplayMode *mode = GetDisplayMode();

        window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
        gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GameEngine Editor");
        gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), mode->w, mode->h);

        pref = adw_header_bar_new();
        gtk_window_set_titlebar(GTK_WINDOW(window), pref);

        theme = gtk_source_style_scheme_chooser_button_new();
        adw_header_bar_pack_start(ADW_HEADER_BAR(pref), theme);
        g_signal_connect(theme, "notify::style-scheme", G_CALLBACK(theme_ev), NULL);

        font_dialog = gtk_font_dialog_new();
        font        = gtk_font_dialog_button_new(font_dialog);
        adw_header_bar_pack_start(ADW_HEADER_BAR(pref), font);
        g_signal_connect(font, "notify::font-desc", G_CALLBACK(font_ev), NULL);

        about = gtk_button_new_with_label("About");
        adw_header_bar_pack_end(ADW_HEADER_BAR(pref), about);
        g_signal_connect(about, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(about_ev), NULL);

        view   = adw_view_switcher_new();
        stack1 = adw_view_stack_new();
        stack2 = adw_view_stack_new();
        button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Game Editor");
        adw_view_stack_add(ADW_VIEW_STACK(stack1), button);
        button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Script Editor");
        adw_view_stack_add(ADW_VIEW_STACK(stack2), button);
        adw_view_switcher_set_stack(ADW_VIEW_SWITCHER(view), ADW_VIEW_STACK(stack1));
        adw_view_switcher_set_stack(ADW_VIEW_SWITCHER(view), ADW_VIEW_STACK(stack2));
        adw_header_bar_pack_end(ADW_HEADER_BAR(pref), view);


        gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));

        return SDL_TRUE;
}
```

I want to see a couple of tabs indicating two view. There no examples in the refernce documentation or in the demos. It doesn't have to look like this I just want a simple example of AdwViewSwitcher. Prefeably one that displays like the image [here](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libadwaita/doc/1-latest/view-switcher-dark.png).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to build graphical interfaces in GTK is using xml instead of creating widgets directly by code. [Workbench](https://flathub.org/apps/re.sonny.Workbench) has a good example of Adw.ViewSwitcher, as well as several other examples. That said, you need at least the following widgets:

- A Window
- A Box as window content
- A Adw.HeaderBar as a Box child
- A AdwViewStack as a Box child
- Adw.ViewSwitcher as title-widget of Adw.HeaderBar

And, if you want the interface to be adaptive

- An AdwViewSwitcherBar as a child of Box
- An AdwBreakpoint as a Window child to hide the Adw.ViewSwitcher and reveal the AdwViewSwitcherBar depending on the size of the window.